# Angular 2+ throws JS error, keeps running brokenly

Tags: angular

I am building an tool with Angular (v. 5) and I am encountering an issue where certain errors seem to crash certain things while the app keeps running. My tool yet has to be fully tested, the errors produced are coding errors, but the problem is that the user experience in case this happens seems completely broken and unreachable for me.

E.g: I am using reactive forms in order to build our dynamic forms. The problem that occurred was that an input could not be mapped to its form control. (In this case a form field within a group in a form array within the main form)

```
cannot find control with name 'XYZ'
```

This happened during testing and it broke the app in such a way that the user could still navigate, but new pages would kinda be rendered below the old one. We have a loading spinner that is shown on init and before data is loaded. Navigating from a broken page onto one that makes an HTTP request loaded the page with its spinners running but actually the requests are never being executed. Also select2 was broken. So while the JS crashed to some degree some core Angular functions were still working, such as the router.

I know the best way to get rid of it is by testing and fixing the errors but this is highly irritating for users. On usersnap, our feedback tool I got many tickets that were subsequent of this initial error and since many things were still rendering it was hard to tell from the screenshots what exactly was going wrong.

Is there any way to at least let the app crash in a more graceful way?

We are using sentry for error logging in production and it is implemented as alternative error handler:

```
export const provider = environment.production ? [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RavenErrorHandler}] : [];
```

But I guess using more than one error handler is not possible?

Addition:
This problem originated from the fact that I had not set up forms correctly.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You seem to be having multiple error points in your code.  "`Is there any way to at least let the app crash in a more graceful way?`" Is that the question you're trying to get answered?

Comment: yes. This tool is my first real app developed in Angular 2+ and I am still learning many things but I have to get the app production ready. I am wondering if there is a way to handle errors such as in creation of dynamic forms in a way that the user at least gets to know an error happened

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to show some code be way more specific if you want help, but in general, your code should account for all possible errors and have error handling in place such that users don't run into errors like this.